# Failed to resolve import "../stores/useStore" Pinia

Tags: vue.js, path, vuex, store, pinia

Trying to add a store state to a child component and writing the path, expecting to retun the store, but getting an error - Failed to resolve import "../stores/useStore" Pinia. But the path is ok.

```js
// Stores/usersStore.js

import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useUsersStore = defineStore('usersStore', {
  state: () => ({
    countries: ['italy', 'usa'],
    })
  }
  
  // Child component
  
  <script>
import { useUsersStore } from '../stores/useUsersStore';  // getting an error at this line
import User from './User.vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    const users = useUsersStore();

    return { users };
  }
 }
 
// Project structure

root - stores/usersStore
     - components/childcomponent
     
     (stores and components at the same folder level)
```

Comment: It's "stores/useUsersStore" in one place and "Stores/usersStore" in another and "stores/usersStore" in yet another. The problem is specific to your project or setup, it's not applicable to Vue or Pinia in general. In case you have the problem in IDE but not on build then it's specific to IDE

Comment: I have the same problem. I think the naming issues was of fast typing for stack overflow and not because its wrong setup in his ide.